# How can I increase the size of a circle with zoom and an animation effect using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented a button and a circle. As soon as you click on the button, the circle is enlarged by 10 times. Unfortunately, this does not happen so nicely. Is there a possibility to add an animation to the enlargement? Unfortunately, I haven't found anything on the internet yet.

```js
function zoom() {
    let example = document.getElementById("a");
    example.style.zoom = 10.0;
  }
```

```css
div.circle {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-color: orange;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="zoom()">Zoom</button>
<div id="a" class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: You may please check my recent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72888215/3807365 about animating a circle on a canvas

Answer (score 1):

The zoom property is [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom). Instead, you should use the transform property and scale the circle.

```js
function zoom() {
  let example = document.getElementById("a");
  example.style.transform = "scale(10,10)";
}
```

```css
div.circle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="zoom()">Zoom</button>
<div id="a" class="circle"></div>
```